# How to click a 'next' button of a window using python

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, pywinauto

I used the below code to connect a opened window(Class type is SunAwtFrame), indeed I able to connect to it.
but unable to click next button of it, my doubt is that 'Next' button may reside inside the frame of that window. Even when I use 'swapy' tool, I am unable to navigate through the controls, indeed not showing the controls actually.
So, how to switch to frame if it is that case and click the 'Next' button.

```
app2 = application.Application()

app2.connect(title_re = u'abc')

dialog = app2.abc

print dialog

next =dialog.Next

print next

next.Click()
```

When I ran the above code I got the error like, Please help me to over come over this

```
#Error#:-

  <pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification object at 0x025F26F0>
  <pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification object at 0x025FA3B0>
  next.Click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 229, in __getattr__
    ctrls = _resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 788, in _resolve_contro
l
    raise e.original_exception
pywinauto.findwindows.WindowNotFoundError
```

Comment: Hi. I am the author of SWAPY tool. It seems like pywinauto could not work with your controls. Please tell me, is the button control gray out in SWAPY list or it is absent at all?

Comment: @SWAPYAutomation Hi, From SWAPY also I am unable to see the controls list(all controls including 'next' button).....

Comment: Unfortunately pywinauto cannot access to non standard controls. You may try to make a click on specific coordinates, or use alternative lib. For example Cobra (win LDTP), it also has module for python.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have been trying automate non standard controls by pywinauto. I am recommending you make a click by coordinates, of course if there are no other tasks except press the button.

> dialog.Click(coords=(x, y))

or

> dialog.ClickInput(coords=(x, y))

Comment: I currently have [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675746/windows-gui-automation-on-legacy-app) so I'll try your answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: @SWAPYAutomation Do you know why no action is triggered on a QWidget window? Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088772/pywinauto-qwidget-click-trigers-no-action